# Is posting in blog format notes from out-of-print book where some content is original and other content is copied word-for-word illegal?

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet, public-domain, publishing

The out-of-print book is *Commutative Algebra* by Matsumura.  For example, you can't buy it on Amazon.

I take notes, solve the exercises, but sometimes in my notes (typed) I just copy word-for-word what is written.

If posting the notes in chunks in a blog format is illegal, what is the best I can do?  For example offer a download with PDF.  I am not deriving any money from this, just wanting to share my notes to anyone who finds them useful.

Comment: Depends on your jurisdiction and how extensive you quote. If you make the quotes explicit, your local laws might allow quoting the text.

Comment: @Polygnome United States

Comment: @Polygnome how does one make a quote explicit?

Comment: Out of print means nothing when it comes to copyright: https://www.copyright.gov/help/faq/faq-duration.html

Comment: @CommutativeAlgebraStudent by using quotation marks (e.g. `"` or guillemets) and stating the source. Also, see https://www.janefriedman.com/sample-permission-letter/

Comment: I will go with making my content mostly all original in its presentation. :)

Comment: It is often not that big a deal to get permission from the author for something like that. Authors don't have a financial stake is the sales of out of print books which are a minor source of income anyway, and are usually more motivated to get people to use and understand their textbooks for prestige purposes.